# docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/basexhttp" is already in use by container

Tags: docker, containers, databases, bash, images

Am I even correctly [following](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12340/23443) the documentation on creating and running a docker container below?

```
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# docker run -d \
>     --name basexhttp \
>     --publish 1984:1984 \
>     --publish 8984:8984 \
>     --volume "$HOME/basex/data":/srv/basex/data \
>     --volume "$HOME/basex/repo":/srv/basex/repo \
>     --volume "$HOME/basex/webapp":/srv/basex/webapp \
>     basex/basexhttp:latest
4b827c082bebe45b8be5b7c956f1ada92407181aeec82dc5f71a63f2c5af537e
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# docker run -ti \
>     --name basexhttp \
>     --publish 1984:1984 \
>     --publish 8984:8984 \
>     --volume "$(pwd)/basex/data":/srv/basex/data \
>     basex/basexhttp:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/basexhttp" is already in use by container "4b827c082bebe45b8be5b7c956f1ada92407181aeec82dc5f71a63f2c5af537e". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@ ~]# 
[root@ ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
4b827c082beb        basex/basexhttp:latest   "/usr/local/bin/mvn-…"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       basexhttp
[root@ ~]#
```

referencing:

https://hub.docker.com/r/basex/basexhttp/

https://docs.basex.org/index.php?title=Docker&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop

where I've copied/pasted what I **think** are the relevant commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to create two different containers, each with the same name. Each time you execute `docker run` it will create a container, and you've named the containers the same with `--name basexhttp`. These names must be unique, even among stopped containers. To delete an unneeded container, you can stop and remove it with:

```
docker container stop basexhttp
docker container rm basexhttp
```

(Note that `docker stop` and `docker rm` also work, but it's easier to read and understand the more verbose syntax)